# Vue 3 router: props and query not working on beforeEach navigation guard

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

Using Vue 3 / Vue Router 4: I'm trying to implement a login screen that redirects to the requested deep link after login. But any prop or query I add to the navigation guard (so I can pass the requested URL to the login component) isn't visible to the login component. Here's the relevant code:

```
// Router
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import Login from "@/views/Login.vue";
import Header from "@/components/Header.vue";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Login",
    components: {
      default: Login,
      Header: Header,
    },
    props: {
      Header: { showMenu: false },
    },
    meta: { requiresAuth: false },
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});

router.beforeEach((to) => {
  if (to.meta.requiresAuth && !router.app.user.isAuthenticated()) {
    return { name: "Login", props: { default: { target: to.name } } };
  }
});
```

```
// Login.vue
<script>
export default {
  name: "Login",

  props: {
    target: {
      type: String,
      default: "Home",
    },
  },

</script>
```

The target property remains at the default value no matter which named route I try to request. Nor does passing the value through the query string appear to work. I'm able to pass properties to components in the route definitions themselves without incident, it's just the navigation guard function that causes problems. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something but the code you posted throws errors for me and the way you handle the navigation guard seems a bit strange (you should always have at least one `next()` in the guard).

Anyway, if I understand correctly and if you insist on using the same route for `Header` and `Login` pages, you could do this in your SFC and remove the guard from router file:

```js
// App.vue

<template>
  <router-view :name="page" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      user: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    page() {
      if (this.$route.meta.requiresAuth && !this.user?.isAuthenticated()) {
        return 'Login'
      }

      return undefined
    }
  }
  created() {
    this.user = <your_method_to_get_user>
  }
}
</script>
```

```js
// Router
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import Login from "@/views/Login.vue";
import Header from "@/components/Header.vue";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Login",
    components: {
      default: Login,
      Header: Header,
    },
    props: {
      Header: { showMenu: false }, // showMenu prop will beaccessible in Header
    },
    meta: { requiresAuth: false },
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});
```

But I'd suggest using 2 different routes for login and header and redirecting from header to login if user not logged in and vice versa via the `next()` as described [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards).